# How to check for a value in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have entered 4 numbers into an array using

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    cin >> choice[i];
}
```

I need to check whether i have entered numbers 1,3,4,6(in any order) into the array

eg:-

```
if choice[0] == 1 && choice[1] == 3 && choice[2] == 4 && choice[3] == 6

else if ........ 1,3,6,4

else if..........1,6,3,4

else if.......1,6,4,3

else if......1,4,6,3

else if......1,4,3,6

....
....

else if.....6,4,3,1
```

this type of checking makes my code too big.

Please help me with an alternative way

Comment: _"in any order"_ Just loop through again and check if you found all four correctly (count the valid numbers).

Comment: Sort the array and then compare with 1, 3, 4, 6.

Comment: This question shows research effort (some at least), it is clear, and (under certain conditions) useful. Why the downvotes?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi Because StackOverflow: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266370/consideration-for-removing-the-downvote-button-from-questions/266670#266670

Comment: Check out my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool count1=false;
bool count2=false;
bool count3=false;
bool count4=false;

for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
cin >> choice[i];
if(choice[i]==1) count1==true;
else if(choice[i]==3) count2=true;
else if(choice[i]==4) count3=true;
else if(choice[i]==6)  count4=true;
}

if(count1 && count2 && count3 && count4) cout<<endl<<"yes, it is!";
```

Comment: You can use array of bool but i guess this one is the easiest approach for you :)

Comment: _"You can use array of bool ..."_ a simple counter variable would be sufficient.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that will not work because counter can have value 4 if all the inserted values are 1 ..
Bool takes less space than int.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo If you use a [`std::bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) here you can use [all](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/all/) to test.

Comment: That's good but for a fresh developer i guess it is better to show him the easiest way that is why i didn't even use arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::is_permutation`:

```
int choice[4];

for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    cin >> choice[i];
}

std::cout << std::is_permutation(std::begin(choice), std::end(choice), std::vector<int>{1, 3, 4, 6}.begin()) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Isn't it an issue here with the lifetime of the temporary `std::vector` used as 3rd argument?

Comment: @Snps Nope, in the same way that the `i` in `for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)` will last the duration of the `for` loop because it is in scope, so the anonymous `std::vector` will last the duration of `std::is_permutation` because it will be in scope.

Comment: But the only thing passed to the function scope of `std::is_permutation` is a copy of the iterator. The temporary is created at the call site, right?

Comment: @Snps The `std::vector` was created in the scope of the `std::is_permutation` call and cannot be freed until that scope closes, which it does when `std::is_permutation` returns.

Comment: [Seems you're right](http://ideone.com/oEK2IE), guess I have to read up some on evaluation order during function calls! :)

Comment: @Snps I tried to find an answer on StackOverflow that explains this, but I couldn't. I think it would make a great question. If you write it up please post the link here, otherwise I'll go ahead and write the question up.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like:

```
std::vector<int> choice(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> choice[i];
}

std::sort(std::begin(choice), std::end(choice));
if (choice == std::vector<int>{1, 3, 4, 6}) { // 1, 3, 4, 6 should be sorted.
    // equal
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/V6q8PV).

Comment: Sorry i'm an absolute beginner in using vectors.i ran your code.It seems i have many errors in my code.


#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<windows.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
std::vector<int> choice(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> choice[i];
}

std::sort(std::begin(choice), std::end(choice));
if (choice == std::vector<int>{1, 3, 4, 6}) { // 1, 3, 4, 6 should be sorted.
    // equal
}
}

Comment: Here's the output...




error C2039: 'sort' : is not a member of 'std'
error C3861: 'sort': identifier not found
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
error C2275: 'std::vector<_Ty>' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Comment: [Live example](https://ideone.com/V6q8PV) works. You have to include `<algorithm>` and compile with C++11 (`-std=c++11` for gcc/clang).